# Position on opening website

Tags: css, html

I have some issue with my position on opening website. I made contact form:

```css
#contactform {
  padding: 20px;
}

#contactform:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.contactbox h1 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contactbox p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

#contact {
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
#contact input[type="url"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #43A047;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

 :-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

 ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<section id="contactform">

  <div class="contactbox">

    <h1>Gauk komercinį pasiūlymą</h1>
    <ul class="unstyled-list">
      <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <input placeholder="Vardas" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <input placeholder="Elektroninis paštas" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <input placeholder="Telefono numeris" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <input placeholder="Internetinė svetainė (nebūtina)" type="url" tabindex="4" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <textarea placeholder="Žinutė..." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </ul>
    <ul class="unstyled-list">
      <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sed molestie ex, nec convallis ligula. Pellentesque orci nunc, commodo vel felis sed, maximus tincidunt augue. Aliquam eu consequat leo, et faucibus ligula. Aenean convallis
          risus quis lacinia auctor.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sed molestie ex, nec convallis ligula.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</section>
```

This form is at the bottom of website. The thing is then I open my index.html it scrolls down all web and opens at this section, and type cursor is blinking at first placeholder(like you ready to type in), so how can i fix this? How can I open index and be at the top, not at the bottom where that form is...

Comment: Do you have `#contact` in your URL?

Comment: The first input has `autofocus`, which is the culprit.

Comment: Mr lister, thanks! It worked!